# Is it possible to create a while loop within a do while loop in c++?

Tags: c++, while-loop, do-while, helper, factorial

```
int main() 
{
    int num;
    char continue_ = 'N';

    do 
    {
        cin>>num;
        
        while(num <=10 && num >= 1)
        {   
            int new_num = factorial(num);
            cout<<new_num;
        }

        cin>> continue_;
            
    }
    while(continue_ == 'y' || continue_ == 'Y' );
    
    return 0;
}
```

I have a factorial function created already that works. My professor wants us to have a while loop within the do-while, that verifies that the num is a min of 1 and a max of 10. However, when I run it infinitely continues printing the answer as a while loop should. I tried applying a break after the print. However, it stops the program all together can anyone help?

Comment: Yes it works as expected. Look at your code: under what conditions will the program exit the inner `while` loop? And how can that condition change inside that loop?

Comment: It is possible to have different kinds of nested loops; however, as you mentioned, if you don't put the break statement, it will be an indefinite loop. regarding your code, while the user enters the num variable, you don't necessarily need a while command, you can replace *while(num <=10 && num >= 1)* with *if(num <=10 && num >= 1)*. And also I can see no break statement nowhere. Please put your updated codes.

Answer (score 1):

If the input 'num' is between 1-10, then program enters to the second while loop and prints new_num. But the 'num' variable value is not updated inside of the second while loop. Therefore the condition of the second while loop is always true. As a result of this, the program will infinitely print 'new_num'. If you want to verify whether the 'num' is between 0-10 then use a 'if' condition instead of 'while' loop.